# Software to redirect audio of specific application to a different playback device

Tags: windows-7, audio, audio-recording, playback

Is there a software to redirect audio of any application software to a different playback device.

For example, I have a software without any advanced settings for audio output. I will then use this software to wrap this application and redirect its sound output to a different playback device.

Comment: Perhaps you'd care to mention your OS?

Comment: oops I am using windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/352787/how-to-set-per-app-sound-outputs-in-windows-10/) for Windows 10 users has a couple of suggestions for Windows 7 users, namely [ChevVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/) and a github project [AudioRouter](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router) that emulates what ChevVolume does for free at least for now. I have no experience with these but these options appear to suit basic needs. You woudln't be able to wrap audio redirection if you're trying to roll your own app, but you could contact the devs of above applications (particularly the github one I suspect) to incorporate it into your application.

As far as options outside of trying to roll your own software, I have experience with on Windows 10 beyond the built-in Advances System Audio settings, if you ever choose to upgrade, [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) is the best I've found thus far.

I liked the design of [Dante Via](https://www.audinate.com/products/software/dante-via) a lot better, but it was so buggy and unreliable I had to give up on it much to my dismay as I was looking for the closest experience I could get to [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) on the Mac. You might try that first and see if that works for you if all you want is cable-less audio routing.

Voicemeeter is an audio mixer app that can also route audio. Here's a quick primer for you on the different Voicemeeter versions: [Vanilla Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) gives you one virtual device (max 3 virtual I/O), [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) gives you two virtual audio device slots (max 5 virtual I/O), and [Voicemeeter Potato](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/potato.htm) gives you three virtual device slots (max 8 virtual I/O).

I recommend going straight for the Potato version, there a few other differences that makes the potato version more polished and easier to work with (I can't remember them at the moment). If you need more virtual devices, you can cause the non-virtual device slots to become virtual devices by grabbing the [Virtual Audio Cable](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) (vanilla version for built-in virtual devices), A+B for 2 more, and finally C+D for potentially 4 additional virtual inputs and outputs to whichever version of Voicemeeter you install. There's also the VB-Audio Hi-Fi Cable edition of the virtual device as well which I haven't messed with as I don't have a need for it just yet.